# Node.js chronological issue

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with node.js. The commands of the program doesn't load cronologically and i don't know how to do it.
I'm trying to download some images and text from database and send it with packs of 8. But node.js runs for loop and command after loop at the same time.

Here's my code:

```
socket.on('background_dinamically', function(data){
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='"+data.cathegory+"'" , function(err, rows, fields){
            var count = 0;
            var array_elements = [];
            if(err){
                socket.emit('errorserver');
            }else{
                for (var i = rows.length - 1, count; i >= 0; i-- & count ++) {
                    array_elements.push(rows[i]);
                    if (count == 8) {
                        socket.emit('image_loading_background', [array_elements, data]);
                        count = 0;
                        array_elements = [];
                    }
                };

                if(count > 0 && count < 8 && count != 0) { 
                    socket.emit('image_loading_background', [array_elements, data]);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc, first I would check if synchronisation can be done on the client side. If you force your nodejs app to synchronize before sending data to the client, scalability suffers.

If you cannot do without synchronizing on the server side, you can choose between spaghetti code or a sync lib.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of asynchronous (not chronological) programming. By default, node will work on I/O operations in parallel as you are seeing. To get other behaviors including chronological (in serial), parallel batches, as well as error handling helpers, have a look at one of the many [flow control libraries](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-async-flow) available. Specifically, I recommend [caolan/async](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Comment: And there's any way to do it without an external library? Thanks!

Comment: Yes! How do you think the external libraries do it? The point is, the flow control patterns are just that: common patterns, so it makes sense to factor them out into reusable libraries. However, the basic techniques for doing it low level involve some nesting callbacks, queues of work to due, and storing indexes and counters for the most part. Check out the source code for any of those libraries to see how they work.